# For which $p \in \mathbb R$ does a signed measure on $([0, 1], \mathcal B([0, 1]))$ exist such that $\mu([0, x]) = x^p \sin(1/x)$?

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, signed-measures

I am currently preparing for a measure theory exam and struggling with the following problem:

For which $p \in \mathbb R$ does a signed measure on $([0, 1], \mathcal B([0, 1]))$ exist such that $\mu([0, x]) = x^p \sin(1/x)$?

Furthermore, it is required to determine a Hahn-decomposition of $\mu$.

So far I have tried differentiating $x^p \sin(1/x)$ and then analyzing where the derivative, call it $f$, is positive and negative (for the Hahn-decomposition).
Then one might set $\mu(A) = \int_A f \mathrm d \lambda$.
I have done this in similar exercises. However, what bothers me is the point $0$. But maybe the worry is not necessary, since ignoring single points does not hurt when finding densities with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$.

Regarding which $p \in \mathbb R$ is permissible, I only know that from $\mu([0, 0]) = 0$ it follows that $p > 0$.

I'd appreciate if somebody could back up my thoughts or provide an alternative strategy.

Comment: Hint: For any $f\in\mathcal{C}([0,1]$, define $Tf=\int_{[0,1]}f(x)x^p\sin(1/x)\,dx$. $\|Tf\|\leq\|f\|_u\int_{[0,1]}x^p$. For $p>-1$ $T$ defines a bounded linear operator. The Riezs representation theorem may come in handy.